# PDFsharp - How to create a 2nd page

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I can't find documentation in PDFsharp to show how to add a 2nd page using C#!

As an example, over in VB6 I use a PDF creation method called mjwPDF.  To indicate that the page is finished

```
objPDF.PDFEndPage
```

And to start a new page:

```
objPDF.PDFNewPage
```

My PDFsharp initial settings:

```
// Create a new PDF document
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// Create an empty page
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
//page.Contents.CreateSingleContent().Stream.UnfilteredValue;

// Get an XGraphics object for drawing
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
```

Unfortunately in PDFsharp I can't find out how to start/write on a new page.  I see these commands but can't get a second page started.

```
document.AddPage();
document.InsertPage();
```

I've tried both of these but my output continues to write on page 1, not page 2.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the actual code:

```
private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new PDF document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

    // Create an empty page
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
    //page.Contents.CreateSingleContent().Stream.UnfilteredValue;

    // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

    // Create a font
    XFont fontArial20 = new XFont("Arial", 20, XFontStyle.Bold, options);
    XFont fontArial14 = new XFont("Arial", 14, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
    XFont fontArial14Bold = new XFont("Arial", 14, XFontStyle.Bold, options);
    XFont fontArial10 = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
    XFont fontArial10Bold = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Bold, options);
    XFont fontArial9 = new XFont("Arial", 9, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
    XFont fontArial9Bold = new XFont("Arial", 9, XFontStyle.Bold, options);
    XFont fontArial8 = new XFont("Arial", 8, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
    XFont fontArial8Bold = new XFont("Arial", 8, XFontStyle.Bold, options);

    XFont fontCour10 = new XFont("Courier New", 10, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
    XFont fontCour10Bold = new XFont("Courier New", 10, XFontStyle.Bold, options);

    XFont printFontCour8 = new XFont("Courier New", 8, XFontStyle.Regular);
    XFont printFontCour8Bold = new XFont("Courier New", 8, XFontStyle.Bold);
    XFont printFontCour8Italic = new XFont("Courier New", 8, XFontStyle.Italic);
    XFont printFontCour10 = new XFont("Courier New", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);
    XFont printFontCour10Bold = new XFont("Courier New", 10, XFontStyle.Bold);
    XFont printFontCour14 = new XFont("Courier New", 14, XFontStyle.Bold);

    XFont printFontCour10BoldItalic = new XFont("Courier New", 10, XFontStyle.Bold | XFontStyle.Italic);

    XFont printFontArial8 = new XFont("Arial", 8, XFontStyle.Regular);
    XFont printFontArial10 = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);
    XFont printFontArial10Bold = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Bold);
    XFont printFontArial14 = new XFont("Arial", 14, XFontStyle.Bold);

    // Create pen.
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    Pen blackPen3 = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    Pen blackPen1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    Pen greyPen1 = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1);
    Pen greyPen3 = new Pen(Color.Gray, 3);
    Pen lightgreyPen1 = new Pen(Color.LightGray, 1);

    //define margins
    double leftMargin = 40.0;
    double rightMargin = 570.0;
    double topMargin = 20.0;
    double lineTop = 0d;
    double lineFooter = 780d;

    double rowStep = 12d;
    //double rowStep = 15d;

    double newRow = topMargin + rowStep;
    double beginRow = newRow;
    double currentRow = beginRow;
    double currentRowCol2 = 0;

    double firstCustomerRow = 100d;
    //double firstCustomerRow = 110d;
    //float firstCustomerRow = 120;
    double txtShift = 8d;

    string hcString = string.Empty; //---added 6-26-13

    //---top section--------------------------------------------------------
    // draw the TIW Logo
    Image Logo = Image.FromFile(Settings.Default.LogoPath);
    gfx.DrawImage(Logo, leftMargin, topMargin);

    // title & version
    string textToPrint = "TIW Purchasing - Master Buy List";
    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial14Bold, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 160, topMargin + 30);

    string eiNum = listView1.Items[0].Text;
    string eiDesc = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text;
    string partNum = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[2].Text;
    string partDesc = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[3].Text;
    string price = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[4].Text;
    string partType = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[5].Text;
    string partQty = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[6].Text; 

    if (eiDesc.Length > 80)
        eiDesc = eiDesc.Substring(0, 80) + "...";

    textToPrint = eiNum + " - " + eiDesc;
    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10Bold, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, topMargin + 70);

    int lineInc = 70;

    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listView1.Items[i].Text == eiNum)
        {
            lineInc = lineInc + 12;

            if (lineInc >= 480)
            {
                //PdfPage page2 = document.AddPage();

                document.AddPage();
                XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

                // title & version
                textToPrint = "TIW Purchasing - Master Buy List - (continued)";
                gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial14Bold, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 160, topMargin + 30);

                lineInc = 70;
            }

            partNum = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;
            partDesc = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text;
            price = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text;
            partType = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text;
            partQty = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[6].Text;

            textToPrint = partNum;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 10, topMargin + lineInc);

            //textToPrint = partDesc.Substring(0, 50);
            textToPrint = partDesc;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 70, topMargin + lineInc);

            textToPrint = price;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 450, topMargin + lineInc);

            textToPrint = partType;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 470, topMargin + lineInc);

            textToPrint = partQty;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 490, topMargin + lineInc);
        }
        else
        {
            lineInc = lineInc + 16;
            eiNum = listView1.Items[i].Text;
            eiDesc = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;

            if (eiDesc.Length > 80)
                eiDesc = eiDesc.Substring(0, 80) + "...";

            textToPrint = eiNum + " - " + eiDesc;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10Bold, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, topMargin + lineInc);

            lineInc = lineInc + 12;

            partNum = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;
            partDesc = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text;
            price = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text;
            partType = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text;
            partQty = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[6].Text;

            textToPrint = partNum;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 10, topMargin + lineInc);

            //textToPrint = partDesc.Substring(0, 20);
            textToPrint = partDesc;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 70, topMargin + lineInc);

            textToPrint = price;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 450, topMargin + lineInc);

            textToPrint = partType;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 470, topMargin + lineInc);

            textToPrint = partQty;
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, fontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 490, topMargin + lineInc);

        }
    }

    //------ footer
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    String.Format("{0:F}", dateTime);
    textToPrint = "eView " + EViewMethods.eviewVersion + "                       " + Environment.UserName + "                     " + String.Format("{0:F}", dateTime);
    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontCour8Italic, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, lineFooter);

    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        document.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        Process.Start(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
```

Here's my corrected code:

```
    private void createPDF()
    {
        // Create a new PDF document
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        // Create an empty page
        PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

        // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

        XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

        // Create fonts
        XFont printFontArial8 = new XFont("Arial", 8, XFontStyle.Regular);
        XFont printFontArial10 = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);
        XFont printFontArial10Bold = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Bold);
        XFont printFontCour10BoldItalic = new XFont("Courier New", 10, XFontStyle.Bold | XFontStyle.Italic);
        XFont printFontArial14 = new XFont("Arial", 14, XFontStyle.Bold);
        XFont printFontCour8 = new XFont("Courier New", 8, XFontStyle.Regular);

        // Create pen.
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        float lineInc = 20.0f;
        //--------------------------------------------

        //define margins
        double leftMargin = 40.0;
        //double rightMargin = 570.0;
        double topMargin = 20.0;
        //double lineTop = 0d;
        //double lineFooter = 780d;

        string eiNum = string.Empty;
        string eiDesc = string.Empty;
        string partNum = string.Empty;
        string partDesc = string.Empty;
        string price = string.Empty;
        string partType = string.Empty;
        string partQty = string.Empty;
        string thisEndItem = string.Empty;

        string textToPrint = string.Empty;
        int pageCounter = 0;

        string filename = string.Empty;

        bool morePages = true;

        while (morePages)
        {
            if (pageCounter == 0 && counter == 0)
            {
                // draw image/logo
                Image Logo = Image.FromFile(Settings.Default.LogoPath);
                gfx.DrawImage(Logo, leftMargin, 35f);

                // draw title
                textToPrint = "TIW Purchasing - Master Buy List";
                gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial14, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 160f, 54f);

                // date
                DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
                textToPrint = thisDay.ToString("d");
                gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 280f, 76f);

                eiNum = listView1.Items[0].Text;
                eiDesc = listView1.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text;

                if (eiDesc.Length > 80)
                    eiDesc = eiDesc.Substring(0, 80) + "...";

                textToPrint = eiNum + " - " + eiDesc;
                gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10Bold, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, topMargin + 90);
            }
            else if (pageCounter > 0)
            {
                double remainder = counter % amtperpage;
                if (remainder == 0) //---means we're at the top of the page
                {
                    //title & version
                    textToPrint = "TIW Purchasing - Master Buy List";
                    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10Bold, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 120, 54f);
                    textToPrint = "(continued from page " + page + ")";
                    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 400, 54f);
                }
            }

            if (pageCounter == 0)
                lineInc = 90;
            else
                lineInc = 78;

            int stop = counter + amtperpage;

            if (stop > listView1.Items.Count)
                stop = listView1.Items.Count;

            while (counter < stop)
            {
                thisEndItem = listView1.Items[counter].SubItems[0].Text;

                partNum = listView1.Items[counter].SubItems[2].Text;
                partDesc = listView1.Items[counter].SubItems[3].Text;
                price = listView1.Items[counter].SubItems[4].Text;
                partType = listView1.Items[counter].SubItems[5].Text;
                partQty = listView1.Items[counter].SubItems[6].Text;

                if (thisEndItem == eiNum) //---still working on the same end item
                {
                    lineInc += 12;

                    textToPrint = partNum;
                    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 10, topMargin + lineInc);

                    if (partDesc.Length > 70)
                        partDesc = partDesc.Substring(0, 70) + "...";
                    textToPrint = partDesc;
                    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 70, topMargin + lineInc);

                    textToPrint = price;
                    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 600, topMargin + lineInc);

                    textToPrint = partType;
                    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 630, topMargin + lineInc);

                    textToPrint = partQty;
                    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 670, topMargin + lineInc);
                }
                else //---starting a new end item
                {
                    lineInc += 16;

                    eiNum = listView1.Items[counter].Text;
                    eiDesc = listView1.Items[counter].SubItems[1].Text;

                    if (eiDesc.Length > 80)
                        eiDesc = eiDesc.Substring(0, 80) + "...";

                    textToPrint = eiNum + " - " + eiDesc;
                    gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10Bold, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, topMargin + lineInc);
                }

                counter++;
            }

            //---footer-------------------------------
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            textToPrint = "eView " + EViewMethods.eviewVersion + "                       " + Environment.UserName + "                     " + String.Format("{0:F}", dateTime);
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontCour8, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, 1060f);

            printpagenum = pageCounter + 1;
            textToPrint = printpagenum.ToString();
            gfx.DrawString(textToPrint, printFontArial10Bold, Brushes.Black, leftMargin + 740, 1060f);
            //----------------------------------------

            if (counter == listView1.Items.Count)
            {
                morePages = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pageCounter++;
                page = document.AddPage();
                gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
            }
        }

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            document.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            Process.Start(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here's the code in question:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You create a new page with

```
document.AddPage();
```

and then call

```
XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
```

to get a gfx object for the second page (probably this is the missing step).

So repeat those steps from your code sample for every new page:

```
// Create an empty page
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

// Get an XGraphics object for drawing
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
```

Update: In your loop you do the following:

```
document.AddPage();
XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
```

AddPage() returns a "handle" to the newly created page - which you throw in the bin.
Then you call "XGraphics.FromPdfPage()" to create yet another gfx for the first page - which you also would throw in the bin, but you get an exception since there already is a gfx for the first page.

A small change should do the trick:

```
page = document.AddPage();
gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
```

See also:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PageSizes-sample.ashx

"I never dreamed adding a second page could be so difficult! No luck with the suggested code."
PDFsharp includes quite a few working samples to get people going. No luck with the suggested code since you ignored the important part - the values returned by the methods.

Comment: Thanks for the technique!  It seems that the "XGraphics gfx = Xgraphics.FromPdfPage(page);" generates this error: An XGraphics object already exists for this page and must be disposed before a new one can be created.

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure out how to dispose the XGraphics.

Comment: I never dreamed adding a second page could be so difficult!  No luck with the suggested code.

Comment: I'm bogged down with a different problem and haven't been able to return to this problem yet.  I'll return this weekend and attempt to try your techniques.

Comment: Many thanks to you for your solution and the detailed response!  I finally realized what you were trying to tell me.  I was trying to use PdfPage page = document.AddPage(); and XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page) for each page. Your suggestion to use page = document.AddPage(); and gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page) solved the problem!  I will show my corrected code.  Many thanks!

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam can ypu please tell me i have created PDFDocument with only one page with string text ...its working but display after zoom out and zoom in pdf file..how to solve..

Comment: @Archana Better start a new question - and provide more information: your code, a link to a sample PDF file, details about your PDF viewer. Could be a problem with the Adobe Reader or whatever application is used to display the PDF file. Does not sound like a PDFsharp problem.

Comment: Is it possible for pages just to 'flow' into new pages in some sort of dynamic container size? 

Think in terms of var data = newMultiLinedDataSet(3) - would probably fit in one page. 

Then data = new MultiLinedDataSet(300) - not sure how many pages it would need but i would expect PDFSharp to fluidly wrap itself around my data and create the number of pages required for my dataset.

Comment: @ozzy432836 PDFsharp comes with MigraDoc. With MigraDoc you add Paragraphs to your Document and then let MigraDoc add the page breaks when creating a PDF file. PDFsharp is the low-level tool that gives you full control - but you also have to add line breaks and page breaks. http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocSamples.ashx

Comment: ok ill try that out. I've been tearing whats left of my hair over here - drawing rectangles to represent paragraphs then panicking if an order has more than 10 items

Answer (score 3):

Do not forget to update your "canvas" or "graphics" object variable to the new page:

You may be doing something like this:

```
// First time:
this.page = document.AddPage();
this.gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

...

// next time (forgot to update graphics or canvas variable):
this.page = document.AddPage();
```

And, it should be something like:

```
// First time:
this.page = document.AddPage();
this.gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

...

// next time:
this.page = document.AddPage();
// update graphics object, also
this.gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
```

I also made that mistake.

Answer (score -1):

you can print in multiple pages by decreasing the size of "Ypoint" as shown below code.

its given value is "yPoint = yPoint + 40"

change it to "yPoint = yPoint + 8" i.e increment ypoint by +8 in every loop iteration,

reply for any doubts.
refer while loop below

```
        While dr.Read

            username = dr.Item(0)
            Action_Performed = dr.Item(1)
            datetim = dr.Item(2)

            graph.DrawString(username, font, XBrushes.Black, _
               New XRect(40, yPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)

            graph.DrawString(Action_Performed, font, XBrushes.Black, _
              New XRect(280, yPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)

            graph.DrawString(datetim, font, XBrushes.Black, _
               New XRect(420, yPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)
            yPoint = yPoint + 10
            counter += 1
            If counter = 30 Then
                pdfPage = pdf.AddPage()
                graph.Dispose()
                graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)
                font = New XFont("Verdana", 7, XFontStyle.Regular)
                yPoint = 0
                yPoint = yPoint + 100
                counter = 0
            End If
        End While
        Dim pdfFilename As String = "dbtopdf.pdf"
        pdf.Save(pdfFilename)
        Process.Start(pdfFilename)
```

regards,
Shivanand

Comment: It is obvious that smaller fonts allow more lines per page. Larger pages (A3, A2, A1, A0, custom, ...) also allow more lines per page.

Answer (score -2):

Before trying to create a new XGraphics object for the new page, dispose the old existing object:

```
xgrObject.Dispose();
```

Comment: When creating a new XGraphics object, make sure you create it for the correct page. You cannot draw on the second page when you dispose the gfx for the first page and then create another gfx for the same (first) page. You can only have one gfx for any page at a time, but you can create multiple pages and have one gfx for each page. No need to finish one page before you create a gfx for a new page.

Comment: Many thanks for the technique!  It seems like when I create a new gfx it must be a different name, i.e., gfx, gfx1, gfx2,...etc.  This program could encounter a huge list that would require many gfx1-gfx100's.  It would be hard to programatically (sp?) create the new gfx's  because I don't think you can declare a new "XGraphics gfx = Xgraphics.FromPdfPage(page);" where I use a variable name for the new gfx.  If I am reading your comment correctly you might be telling me that the xgrObject.Dispose() will allow me to reuse the same "gfx" when declaring a new one!?!

Comment: Instead of writing "XGraphics gfx = Xgraphics.FromPdfPage(page);" you can simple write "gfx = Xgraphics.FromPdfPage(page);" and re-use the variable you already have. See the other answer above: "Dispose()" is not the problem, you use the wrong "page" object and attempt to create a second gfx for the first page where you should create the first gfx for the second page.

Comment: I'm bogged down with a different problem and haven't been able to return to this problem yet.  I'll return this weekend and attempt to try your techniques.