# PDFsharp auto page add on to many record retrieved from sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, pdfsharp

is it possible to make automatic multipages with PDFsharp in vb.net? 
(I have 1000 records in SQL table, and I want to display them all, but now it's display only one page with 100 :P)

Btw, sry i didn't put my code here..

```
ukupnoNaslov = "Ukp."
        graph.DrawString(ukupnoNaslov, font, XBrushes.Black,
            New XRect(170, zPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)

        izasloDaNaslov = "DA"
        graph.DrawString(izasloDaNaslov, font, XBrushes.Black,
            New XRect(205, zPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)

        izasloNeNaslov = "NE"
        graph.DrawString(izasloNeNaslov, font, XBrushes.Black,
            New XRect(235, zPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)


        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            bm = "Biracko mesto:     " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0)
            ukupnoglasova = "| " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)
            izasloDA = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)
            izasloNE = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3)






            graph.DrawString(bm, font, XBrushes.Black,
            New XRect(40, yPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)

            graph.DrawString(ukupnoglasova, font, XBrushes.Black,
            New XRect(180, yPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)

            graph.DrawString(izasloDA, font, XBrushes.Black,
            New XRect(210, yPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)

            graph.DrawString(izasloNE, fontBold, XBrushes.Black,
            New XRect(240, yPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)

            yPoint = yPoint + 15
        Next
        Dim pdfFilename As String = "D:\Statistika" & vreme & ".pdf"
        pdf.Save(pdfFilename)
```

Comment: `now it's display only one page` <-- means you have some code to show. Please share with us. `automatic multipages` <-- what do you mean by this?

Comment: I'm not on pc right now to show code... Btw my code is from PdfSharp sample, and it work fine except one thing, it show only first 100 record, and there sholud be next page with oder record... And so on, and so on... I don't know how to make auto page add if records hit bottom of the page i need page add and keep retrieving record ond second page..

Comment: Any source code is better than none. I doubt many people here on SO worked with PDFSharp. You say it prints 100 but not more. Is it correct to assume that if it prints 101 record you are fine? A programming problem is deduced using answers to questions like this. What you asked above is not a programming question, it's a "do it for me" request. There is no information about what you have tried, and there should be. Otherwise we have no starting point and this is not a free consulting website.

Comment: BTW, if you used any links (samples, docs, forums), those should be specified in your question, ideally in the logical order you followed them, together with logical reasoning explaining why you followed them, and how all this relates to your problem described above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDFsharp - How to create a 2nd page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143333/pdfsharp-how-to-create-a-2nd-page) - C# or VB makes no big difference, you have to call the same PDFsharp functions to continue on a new page. BTW: It will be simpler with MigraDoc.

Comment: @ThomasH, it's not duplicate Q, beacuse i know how to add page manualy...i need when data from SQL hit bottom of page to automaticli add next page and keep retrieving data... My eng is very bad, so i'm sorry if asked Q wrongly :P

Comment: Use MigraDoc to get new pages automatically. Add pages in your code if you want to stick to PDFsharp. You know how to add pages manually, but you do not add extra pages, you draw all lines on a single page and beyond the page margin. I'm afraid I don't understand what the purpose of this question is. You can write a helper class for PDFsharp that does it "automatically", hiding page and horizontal position inside that class.

Answer (score 0):

MigraDoc comes with PDFsharp. MigraDoc makes creating multi-page documents very simple. MigraDoc creates the required pages automatically.

PDFsharp is a low-level library and you have to keep track of the position on the page and start a new page as needed.

C# samples:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocSamples.ashx

VB.NET sample:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3207