# Text file to PDF conversion code cuts off text vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdfsharp

The text on my text file does not fit onto a single pdf page which the below code generates.

Please note that the text my program writes unto the text file varies in length such that when imported into a WORD environment, may be a 1, 2 or 3 (and so on) page document.

How can I adjust the code to automatically add multiple pdf pages, if necessary, so that no text from my text file is lost/cut out when the pdf file is generated?

Please see the code below:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports PdfSharp
Imports PdfSharp.Drawing
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        Dim line As String
        Dim readFile As System.IO.TextReader = New StreamReader("Text.txt")
        Dim yPoint As Integer = 0

        Dim pdf As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument
        pdf.Info.Title = "Text File to PDF"
        Dim pdfPage As PdfPage = pdf.AddPage
        Dim graph As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)
        Dim font As XFont = New XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.Regular)

        While True
            line = readFile.ReadLine()
            If line Is Nothing Then
                Exit While
            Else
                graph.DrawString(line, font, XBrushes.Black, _
                New XRect(40, yPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)
                yPoint = yPoint + 40
            End If
        End While


        Dim pdfFilename As String = "txttopdf.pdf"
        pdf.Save(pdfFilename)
        readFile.Close()
        readFile = Nothing
        Process.Start(pdfFilename)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: your code needs a reference for the call `process`

Comment: A simple search for "[pdfsharp] second page" finds this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21143712/1015447  You can use MigraDoc which will handle page breaks automatically .http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9426#p9426

Answer (score 0):

- I guess from a recent earnt experience that the horizontal coordinate which at the text stream is cut is defined as `yPoint=840` which sums up to `21` lines.

On that basis, you should add a page dynamically after each threshold = 21 lines got skipped.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            Dim line As String
            Dim readFile As System.IO.TextReader = New StreamReader("Text.txt")
            Dim yPoint As Integer = 0

            Dim pdf As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument
            pdf.Info.Title = "Text File to PDF"
            Dim pdfPage As PdfPage = pdf.AddPage
            Dim graph As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)
            Dim font As XFont = New XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.Regular)

            While True
                line = readFile.ReadLine()
                If line Is Nothing Then
                    Exit While
                Else
                    graph.DrawString(line, font, XBrushes.Black, New XRect(40, yPoint, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopLeft)
                    yPoint = yPoint + 40

'--------------------------- here is the part added ----------------------------------
                    If yPoint = 840 Then
                        pdfPage = pdf.AddPage
                        graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)
                        yPoint = 0
                    End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                End If
            End While


            Dim pdfFilename As String = "txttopdf.pdf"
            pdf.Save(pdfFilename)
            readFile.Close()
            readFile = Nothing
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfFilename)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

End Sub
```